# Compute probability of union of independent events

Tags: probability-theory

Here is the problem statement:

Let $\{C_i\}_{i=1}^k$ be independent with $P(C_i) = p_i$. Argue that at least one of the $C_i$ has probability $$1-\prod_{i=1}^k(1-p_i).$$

All I've managed to wrangle up so far is that 
$$1-P\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^k C_k \right) = P\left[\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^k C_i\right)^c\right] = P\left(\bigcap_{i=1}^k C_i^c\right) = \prod_{i=1}^k P(C_i^c) = \prod_{i=1}^k (1-p_i),$$ where the second equality follows from the fact that the respective complements of independent sets are, likewise, independent.

Where do I go from here? The piece of this that is especially confusing is this: if the probability of some $C_i$ is as stated, why did we list its probability as some $p_i$. It makes me wonder if there is a typo and I am trying to prove this is the probability of one of the $C_i^c$.

Comment: Seems wrong indeed. Let $\Omega = \{1,2,3,4\}$ with $\mathbb{P}(\{i\}) = \frac{1}{4}$, then $C_1 = \{ 1,2\}$ and $C_2 = \{2,3\}$ are independent with $p_1 = p_2 = \frac{1}{2}$. However $1 -\prod_{i=1}^2 (1- p_i) = 1 - \frac{1}{4} = \frac{3}{4}$. Note that neither $C_1^C$ nor $C_2^C$ has probability $\frac{3}{4}$, thus the proposed fix is not correct either.

Comment: Please replace " at least one of the Ci" by "the union of the Ci".

Comment: This is the original wording of the question, but I see now how it is unclear.

Answer (score 0):

> Where do I go from here?

You have shown that: $1-\mathsf P\left(\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^k C_i\right) = \prod\limits_{i=1}^k (1-p_i)$

And wish to show that: $\mathsf P\left(\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^k C_i\right) = 1-\prod_{i=1}^k (1-p_i)$

...

> The piece of this that is especially confusing is this: if the probability of some $C_i$ is as stated, why did we list its probability as some $p_i$.

The event that one of the outcomes occurs is the event that $C_1$ or $C_2$ or ... $C_k$ occurs.   That is the union series: $\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^k C_i$

Comment: Oh, I misread the question. I thought it meant to show that some $p_i$ was equal to the product expression, not the probability of the event "at least one $C_i$." From what I have, this is just algebra.